# How to change the focus inside a form and make the new control deal with the key pressed?

Tags: c#, focus, keydown

I have a form with a search box and a datagridview with the results.
What I need is the search box to always get the focus whenever I press a char or number key, and then process the key. So, for instance, if my focus is on the datagrid, and I press a char, it'll go to the search box. (Additionally, whenever the Up or Down arrows are pressed in the form, the focus will go to the datagrid, but I got no problem with that.)

Now, the code below will work as a charm for chars. When I get to the numbers, though, I can't do it the same way (as my `e.KeyCode.ToString()` will not give me the number, but a "d0" or "numpad0").

```
    private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.tbxSearch.Focused)
        {
            if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.A) && (e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z))
            {
                this.tbxSearch.Focus();
                this.tbxSearch.Text = (e.Shift) ? e.KeyCode.ToString() : e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower();
                this.tbxSearch.SelectionStart = this.tbxSearch.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, I might do it just about the same way, and simply get the last char in the "`e.KeyCode.ToString()`", but it doesn't seem alright to me. I mean, there must be a simpler way of just changing the focus and then making the control deal with the key pressed.

I've tried making it in the `PreviewKeyDown` event, but it won't be triggered by the form (even with the `KeyPreview` property set to `true`):

```
    private void Form_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up))
            this.dgvResults.Focus();
        else
            this.tbxSearch.Focus();
    }
```

So I was left wondering: how can I change the focus on a form and let the new control deal with the key?

Comment: Have you tried e.KeyValue? WHat about special keys like Keys.Delete or Keys.Back? And Modifying keys (I mean like when e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)?

Comment: I've tried, but e.KeyValue gives an int, not a char; I don't care about the special keys, only about alphanumerical, so I won't treat those cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a key is a digit like this:

```
private Keys[] numericKeys =
        {
             Keys.D1,
             Keys.D2,
             Keys.D3,
             Keys.D4,
             Keys.D5,
             Keys.D6,
             Keys.D7,
             Keys.D8,
             Keys.D9,
             Keys.D0,
             Keys.NumPad0,
             Keys.NumPad1,
             Keys.NumPad2,
             Keys.NumPad3,
             Keys.NumPad4,
             Keys.NumPad5,
             Keys.NumPad6,
             Keys.NumPad7,
             Keys.NumPad8,
             Keys.NumPad9
};

...

bool isDigit = numericKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode);
```

or like this:

```
bool isDigit = Char.IsDigit((char)e.KeyCode);
```

or:

```
bool isLetterOrDigit = char.IsDigit((char)e.KeyCode);
```

Comment: Arie, sorry for not making it sufficiently clear, my issue is not to recognize if the key is a digit, but with adding it in the textbox. Your suggestion of making a (char) cast, though, worked very well... for digits on the regular keyboard, but not for the numpad... it translates to 'a'..'i'